# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/data/user/0/MyApp.MyApp is denied? (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: save, apk

I get the path of apk folder of my app:

```
string apkFileFolder = FilesDir.Path;
```

And get the path of folder in it

```
string pathToFromServerFolder = apkFileFolder + "/backup/fromserver";
```

But when I try to save a zip file in it:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pathToFromServerFolder, basedataZipFile);
```

I get error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/data/user/0/MyApp.MyApp/files/backup/fromserver' is denied.
```

My question is if it is possible to confugure my application to be able to save files in that folder or it is impossible no matter what I do?